# When clicked inside div that is toggled to show, it toggles up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an annoying problem, I have a button that toggles a dropdown, my intention is to hide the div when clicked on the button again, which toggle achieves, and to hide the dropdown when clicked outside why my current jquery does. However when clicking inside the div itself, it slides back up.

HTML >

```
<div class="navPanel">

<!-- NAV -->

<nav>

<ul id="navBar"> 

<div class="dynamicNav">

<div class="menu1Container">
<li class="menu1">Books

<!-- DropDown1-->
<div id="dropdownContainer-1"> 

</div>
</li>
</div>
</div>

</ul>

</nav>
```

Jquery >

```
$(function(){
 $(".menu1").click(function(){
   $("#dropdownContainer-1").slideToggle(90);
});

 $(document).click(function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).is(".menu1") && !$(event.target).is(".menu1")) {
     $("#dropdownContainer-1").slideUp(90); //make all inactive
   }
    });

});
```

The obvious problem is event target, I tried using a similar method ->

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
 var target = e.target;
 if (!$(target).is('.menu1') && !$(target).parents().is('.menu1')) {
 $('#dropdownContainer-1').slideUp(90);
 }
  });
```

If you could help me figure this one out, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I've appeared to have fixed it lol, after 2 hours of looking for a solution. I simply unwrapped the <li> surround menu1 from the dropdown container. I left the Menu1Container div wrapped around the dropdown div and used the second jquery script I showed in my post. If anyone however has any better solutions, I'd like to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
$(event.target).closest(".menu1").length == 0
```

```js
$(".menu1").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();   // avoid to propagate to document click
  if ($(event.target).is(".menu1")) {
    $("#dropdownContainer-1").slideToggle(90);
    console.log('Menu1 toggled clicking menu1');
  }
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".menu1").length == 0 &&
     $("#dropdownContainer-1").is(':visible')) {
    // if not inside area of menu1
    $("#dropdownContainer-1").slideUp(90); //make all inactive
    console.log('Menu1 closed clicking outside menu1');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="navPanel">

    <!-- NAV -->

    <nav>

        <ul id="navBar">

            <div class="dynamicNav">

                <div class="menu1Container" style="border-style: dotted;width:50%;">
                    <li class="menu1">Books

                        <!-- DropDown1-->
                        <div id="dropdownContainer-1">
                            <p>1111</p>
                            <p>1111</p>
                            <p>1111</p>
                            <p>1111</p>
                            <p>1111</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ul>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't appear to fix the problem, it still slides back up once clicked inside the div.

Comment: @stepho Snippet updated. Could you try and let me know? Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, This works perfectly!, thanks :)